# Null Pointer Exception with basic button from view

Tags: java, android, button, nullpointerexception

Im just doing the simplest thing ever. I have a layout with 2 buttons and an `ImageView` and I'm getting a `NullPointerException` when I find it by id!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:weightSum="1">
<Button android:text="Button" android:id="@+id/button1" android:layout_width="wrap_content"    android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
<Button android:text="Button" android:id="@+id/button2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
<ImageView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/imageView1" android:layout_width="76dp" android:layout_weight="0.12"></ImageView>
</LinearLayout>
```

OnCreate:

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        one = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        two = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        one.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),1);
            }
        });

        two.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 2);  
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: clean application once and try again still not working then post error log.

Comment: Please share the stacktrace of the nullpointerexception

Answer (score -1):

Check your code, I did not see obvious logic that will throw NPE. Maybe it is in code that is not posted.
We can check the log to see which line throws the exception by following command:
*adb logcat*